# binding to cursor movement doesnt change INSERT mark

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need to perform a quick check everytime the user changes the insertion point, by arrows, mouseclick, etc... so I bound it thus:

```
text.bind("<Button-1>", insertchanged)

def insertchanged(event):
    pos=text.index(INSERT)
    n=text.tag_names(INSERT)
        ...
```

but I found out that pos is still the position *before* the user changed it! How do I find the new position (a general solution, if possible: I have to bind it to home,end, pgup, pgdown,...)

thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach. For one, you'll need to bind to just about everything in order to track the insertion point (remember: it changes every time you insert or delete anything).

Second, changes happen to the widget based on class bindings and, by default, any bindings you create will fire *before* the class bindings. You can work around these issues, but it's tricky. For example, to work around the event handling order, search around this site and others for "bind tags" or "bindtags".

There is, however, an almost foolproof solution. The downside is that it requires some serious Tcl voodoo: you have to replace the internal widget with a proxy that calls a callback whenever the insertion point changes. I've included a complete working example, below.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.text = CustomText(self, wrap="word")
      self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
      self.label = tk.Label(self, anchor="w")
      self.label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

      # this is where we tell the custom widget what to call
      self.text.set_callback(self.callback)

  def callback(self, result, *args):
      '''Updates the label with the current cursor position'''
      index = self.text.index("insert")
      self.label.configure(text="index: %s" % index)

class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Danger Will Robinson!
        # Heavy voodoo here. All widget changes happen via
        # an internal Tcl command with the same name as the 
        # widget:  all inserts, deletes, cursor changes, etc
        #
        # The beauty of Tcl is that we can replace that command
        # with our own command. The following code does just
        # that: replace the code with a proxy that calls the
        # original command and then calls a callback. We
        # can then do whatever we want in the callback. 
        private_callback = self.register(self._callback)
        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {actual_widget callback args} {

                # this prevents recursion if the widget is called
                # during the callback
                set flag ::dont_recurse(actual_widget)

                # call the real tk widget with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $actual_widget]]

                # call the callback and ignore errors, but only
                # do so on inserts, deletes, and changes in the 
                # mark. Otherwise we'll call the callback way too 
                # often.
                if {! [info exists $flag]} {
                    if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete}) ||
                        ([lrange $args 0 2] == {mark set insert})} {
                        # the flag makes sure that whatever happens in the
                        # callback doesn't cause the callbacks to be called again.
                        set $flag 1
                        catch {$callback $result {*}$args } callback_result
                        unset -nocomplain $flag
                    }
                }

                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy _{widget} {callback}
        '''.format(widget=str(self), callback=private_callback))

    def _callback(self, result, *args):
        self.callback(result, *args)

    def set_callback(self, callable):
        self.callback = callable


if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  frame = Example(root)
  frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: damn hard for me to understand it at first, but I made it work! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WidgetRedirector` from standard library's `idlelib` (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/redirector.py), which seems to do what Bryan proposed:

```
import tkinter as tk
from idlelib.WidgetRedirector import WidgetRedirector


root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.grid()


def on_mark(*args):
    print("mark", args)
    return original_mark(*args)

def on_insert(*args):
    print("insert", args)
    return original_insert(*args)

def on_delete(*args):
    print("delete", args)
    return original_delete(*args)


redirector = WidgetRedirector(text)
original_mark = redirector.register("mark", on_mark)
original_insert = redirector.register("insert", on_insert)
original_delete = redirector.register("delete", on_delete)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The link in the answer gives a 404.

Comment: @BryanOakley, fixed now (they had renamed files)