# How to dynamically insert text in tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I want to create a log window where I show records of error or success messages.
Please tell me any solution to insert text in `text_box` from any widget in current application.

Is any solution like we use `textvariable`

Purpose:
Suppose we have two tabs, in one we are downloading something and some error comes in it, then this error is inserted in the text box of the other tab.

I am updating my question to get better answer.

## File Structure:

[image]

`downloader.py`

```py
import tkinter as tk


class DownloadWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        ################# self configure ##########################
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        ############### entry ################################
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.entry.insert(0, 'I am error send me to Logs...')

        ################ Button #################################
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Send to Log')
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

`insert.py`

```py
"""
Help me to write a function in this module for button in downloader
"""
```

`logs.py`

```py
import tkinter as tk


class LogWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        ################# self configure ##########################
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.text_box = tk.Text(self, wrap=None, bg='black', font='roboto 14 bold')
        self.text_box.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.scroller = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.text_box.yview, orient='vertical')
        self.text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroller.set)
        self.scroller.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nse')

        self.text_box.tag_configure('welcome', foreground='white', background='black')
        self.text_box.tag_configure('error', foreground='red')
        self.text_box.tag_configure('success', foreground='green')

        self.text_box.insert('end', '>>> Welcome to Log Window', 'welcome')
        self.text_box.insert('end', '\n>>> Completed', 'success')
        self.text_box.insert('end', '\n>>> Something Wrong in Data Download', 'error')
```

`luncher.py`

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from Test.logs import LogWindow
from Test.downloader import DownloadWindow
root = tk.Tk()

base_tab = ttk.Notebook(root)
base_tab.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


base_tab.add(DownloadWindow(base_tab), text='Download')
base_tab.add(LogWindow(base_tab), text='Logs')

root.mainloop()
```

### Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

## Final Update and Goal Achived

Added In `downloader.py`

```py
        self.button.config(command=self.create_log)

    def create_log(self):
        write_log(self.entry.get())
```

Added In `insert.py`

```py
def write_log(text):
    with open('logs_data.txt', 'a') as log:
        log.write(f'\n{text}')
```

Added In `logs.py`

```py
        self.show_log()

    def show_log(self):
        global file_name, cached_stamp
        stamp = os.path.getmtime(file_name)
        if stamp != cached_stamp:
            with open(file_name, 'r') as log:
                data = log.readlines()
                self.text_box.insert('end', f'\n{data[-1]}', 'success')
        cached_stamp = stamp
        self.after(1000, self.show_log)
```

### Conclusion

I am appending each log in .txt file and reading them in every sec. from LogWindow and detecting change. If change occur then inserting in Text widget.

Comment: You can nsert text into it by calling `self.text_box.insert()` — the same way you do it in the `Windows.__init__()` method,

Comment: @martineau sir I can't create object in insert module because I am using insert module multiple time. Is there any function based solution.

Comment: Despite your update, you question remains unclear. I think I know how to create a `Text`-like widget that supports a `textvariable=` option. However it's (still) unclear how having one fits into what you want in the `insert` module. None of your code contains any clues as to the interface you desire it to have (other than maybe it contains a function of some sort). You seem to have an idea, but we can't read your mind…

Comment: @martineau: the "function-based solution" is to call the `insert` method on the text widget. `insert` is a function. This is literally the only way to insert text into a widget.

Comment: @Bryan: What object? Where is it created? How do other modules access it?

Comment: @BryanOakley sir according to screenshot presentation is there any other way to achieve this. Instead of Text widget.

Comment: @martineau sir I just want that error text in log tab.

Comment: Manish: I know, I just don't understand *how* you want that to happen. Just saying it's done in some code in certain module does not describe an interface nor sample usage of it.

Comment: The title of your question specifically asks how to insert text into a text widget. The only answer to that can be found  in the documentation, and that is to call the `insert` method. That's it. That's all there is.

Comment: @martineau Sir, forget my module structure and see both  screenshots, do you see any idea to achieve this?

Comment: Manish: See @BryanOakley's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565476/355230) to another question that has the defintion of a `Text`-like widget that supports a `textvariable`

Comment: @BryanOakley  Sir After a lot of thinking, I have reached to a solution, can you see this and tell me am I right?

Comment: @martineau Sir After a lot of thinking, I have reached to a solution, can you see this and tell me am I right?

Comment: Manish: From what I can tell it looks like it would work. I thought you wanted something more dynamic than that which would cause the various `Text` widget associated it to update themselves automatically whenever `StringVar` was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. I don't know if it's a language barrier or just a problem with terminology. I'm guessing that you're not actually asking how to insert text into a widget since that is clearly documented, but rather how to create the widget in one class and access it from another.

If that is the case, then my recommendation is to do two things: create a method in `LogWindow` to insert text into the text widget, and then call that method from anywhere else in the app.

### Create a logging method in LogWindow

The firs step is to create a function in `LogWindow` that other objects can use to add data to the log. The following example creates an `info` method which accepts a string and adds it to the text widget:

```
class LogWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.text_box = tk.Text(...)
        ...
        
    def info(self, message):
        self.text_box.insert("end", message)
        if not message.endswith("\n"):
            self.text_box.insert("end", "\n")
```

### Modify DownloadWindow to accept instance of LogWindow

Next, you need to make sure that other code can call this method. You can either do that by setting a global variable, by creating a global controller that all tabs can access, or by passing the reference to the other tabs.

Arguably the simplest method is to just pass the instance to other classes. You can do that by first modifying `DownloadWindow` to accept the log window as a parameter:

```
class DownloadWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, logwindow):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.logger = logwindow
```

Once you do that, you can use `self.logger.info("...")` anywhere in the class to send a message to the log window.

### Passing the instance of LogWindow to DownloadWindow

The final step is to pass the instance of `LogWindow` to `DownloadWindow`. This requires creating the instance of `LogWindow` first, saving a reference, and passing that reference to `DownloadWindow`

```
log_window = LogWindow(base_tab)
download_window =  DownloadWindow(base_tab, log_window)

base_tab.add(download_window, text='Download')
base_tab.add(log_window, text='Logs')
```