# Python Tkinter: Scrolling two text boxes at the same time; lines get out of sync

Tags: python, text, tkinter, scroll, scrollbar

I have a `Text` widget, `textbox`, where the user can type, and another `Text` widget, `linenumbers`, directly to the left of it which displays line numbers. I have it working, but with one problem: the more lines I create, the more the two `Text` widgets get out of sync when scrolled.

[Here's a gif showing what happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt9im.gif)

And here's my code (`scroll_both` and `update_scroll` came from another StackOverflow thread):

```
class MainGUI:

    def scroll_both(self, action, position, type=None):
        self.textbox.yview_moveto(position)
        self.linenumbers.yview_moveto(position)

    def update_scroll(self, first, last, type=None):
        self.textbox.yview_moveto(first)
        self.linenumbers.yview_moveto(first)
        self.scrollbar_y.set(first, last)

    def on_textbox_update(self, event):
        modified = self.textbox.edit_modified()
        if modified:
            #If the number of lines in the textbox has changed:
            if self.linecount != self.textbox.index("end").split('.')[0]:
                #Update textbox's linecount
                self.linecount = self.textbox.index("end").split('.')[0]
                # Clear the line count sidebar
                self.linenumbers.config(state="normal")
                self.linenumbers.delete(0.0, "end")
                # Fill it up again
                for LineNum in range(1, int(self.linecount)):
                    self.linenumbers.insert(self.linenumbers.index("end"), str(LineNum)+"\n", "justifyright")
                    if len(str(LineNum)) == 1:
                        self.linenumbers.config(width=2)
                    else:
                        self.linenumbers.config(width=len(str(LineNum)))
                self.linenumbers.config(state="disabled")

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        Grid.rowconfigure(master, 1, weight=1)
        Grid.columnconfigure(master, 2, weight=1)

        self.linenumbers = Text(master, width=2, borderwidth=0, takefocus=0, padx=6, fg="gray")
        self.linenumbers.config(font="TkTextFont")
        self.linenumbers.tag_configure("justifyright", justify="right")
        self.linenumbers.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky=NSEW)

        self.textbox = Text(master, padx=6, borderwidth=0, wrap=NONE)
        self.textbox.config(font="TkTextFont")
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2, sticky=NSEW)
        self.textbox.bind("<<Modified>>", self.on_textbox_update)

        self.scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(master)
        self.scrollbar_y.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=2, sticky=NSEW)
        self.scrollbar_y.config(command=self.scroll_both)
        self.textbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.update_scroll)
        self.linenumbers.config(yscrollcommand=self.update_scroll)

root = Tk()
MainGUI = MainGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For an alternate way to do line numbers which draws numbers only for the visible lines, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375233/7432 One advantage that implementation has is that it works with lines that are different heights, have embeded widgets, and so on.

Comment: @BryanOakley Works great, thanks a lot.

Comment: @BryanOakley Actually there is one issue. When I try to paste something into the textbox and there's nothing selected, it gives this error and crashes: `File "main.py", line 47, in _proxy`
    `result = self.tk.call(cmd)`
`_tkinter.TclError: text doesn't contain any characters tagged with "sel"`