# Using external font file for a Tkinter text widget with PIL

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I saw a recipe in [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580778-tkinter-custom-fonts/) regarding the use of PIL/Pillow on Tkinter. The examples used were for labels.

I was wondering and would like to know if it can be done on a text widget so that we could use a external font instead of what is available in the user's machine.

EDIT 1: I seen a way to make it possible using this [posted by Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369470/tkinter-adding-line-number-to-text-widget/16375233#16375233) regarding line numbers (although the project I'm working does not have line numbers) but I can't seem to get a grip on how to add the custom font code in the recipe