# Handling TclError in Text Selection event thrown by call proxy

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to use the Selection event in a Text widget with modifications similar to [Bryan Oakley's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369470/tkinter-adding-line-number-to-text-widget) (the proxy has to be there for another feature). In the event callback I need to get the sel.last index, while the button is still clicked in order to get the selection in "real time":

```
import tkinter as tk                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                           
class T(tk.Text):                                                                                                              
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                       
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)                                                                                
                                                                                                                           
        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"                                                                                         
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)                                                                            
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)                                                                            
                                                                                                                           
        self.bind('<<Selection>>', self._on_selection)                                                                         
                                                                                                                           
    def _proxy(self, *args):                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                           
        cmd = (self._orig,) + args                                                                                             
        print("cmd: " + str(cmd))                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        return self.tk.call(cmd)                                                                                               
                                                                                                                           
    def _on_selection(self, event):                                                                                            
        print(self.index('sel.last'))                                                                                          
                                                                                                                           
root = tk.Tk()                                                                                                                 
text = T()                                                                                                                     
text.pack()                                                                                                                    
text.insert(tk.END, 'asdf' * 20)                                                                                               
root.mainloop()
```

The app crashes with an unhandled exception on the second click (or selection) in the Text widget (because the selection gets deleted on Button-1, before querying it in Selection):

```
_tkinter.TclError: text doesn't contain any characters tagged with "sel"
```

Now, the exception cannot be solved by handling it in the Selection event callback as the exception gets thrown in the main loop. A simple solution is to modify the _proxy method and add exception handling to the sensitive call there:

```
    def _proxy(self, *args):                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                           
        cmd = (self._orig,) + args                                                                                             
        print("cmd: " + str(cmd))                                                                                              
                                                                                                                           
        if args[0] == 'index' and args[1] == 'sel.last':                                                                       
            try:                                                                                                               
                return self.tk.call(cmd)                                                                                       
            except:                                                                                                            
                return None                                                                                                    
        else:                                                                                                                  
            return self.tk.call(cmd)
```

My two questions:

1. My solution feels a little bit hacky (and not too robust); is there a more elegant way to handle the exception further "down" on the stack (in the event)?
2. How can I check (using a tkinter function) in the Selection callback whether the sel.last is accessible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized I don't necessarily have to use the 'sel.last' tag to get the actual selection before Button-1 release; I can use 'insert' instead, as the cursor is automatically moving with the mouse while the button is pressed.
This way, I answered my second question which makes the first question unnecessary (or at least postpones it).