# Tkinter custom entry widget exception

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to create a custom Tkinter `Entry widget` that will convert lowercase characters to uppercase before the characters are inserted into the widget. I know there are solutions that bind key release events to a widget with a function to get the widget text and then convert to uppercase and reinsert the text. But those solutions display the lowercase character before the conversion occurs, which I prefer not to do.

I'm trying to use a custom Entry widget based on code shared by Bryan Oakley - [Tkinter adding line number to text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369470/tkinter-adding-line-number-to-text-widget)

This code works great for a custom `Text widget` and I have used it in other applications.

Now I'm trying to use the same approach to create a custom Entry widget. Here is sample code that incorporates both a custom Text widget and custom Entry widget:

```
from tkinter import *

class CustomText(Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)

    def _proxy(self, *args):

        if args[0] == "insert" and args[1] == "insert":
           args =('insert', 'insert', args[2].upper())

        cmd = (self._orig,) + args
        result = self.tk.call(cmd)
        return result

class CustomEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)

    def _proxy(self, *args):

        if args[0] == "insert" and args[1] == "insert":
           args =('insert', 'insert', args[2].upper())

        cmd = (self._orig,) + args
        result = self.tk.call(cmd)
        return result

def get_text():
    print("TEXT widget text = ", mytext.get("1.0", "end"))
    print("ENTRY widget text = " ,entryvar.get())

root = Tk()

entryvar = StringVar()

root.geometry("300x300")
myframe = Frame(root, width = 300, height = 300)
Label(myframe, text="TEXT WIDGET").pack(side = TOP)
myframe.pack(side = TOP)
mytext = CustomText(myframe, width = 30, height=1, wrap="none")
mytext.pack(side = TOP)
Label(myframe, text="ENTRY WIDGET").pack(side = TOP)
myentry = CustomEntry(myframe,  textvariable=entryvar, width = 30)
myentry.pack(side = TOP)

Button(myframe, text="Get Entry Widget Text", command=get_text).pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

The solutions works for the `CustomText` widget. As you can see the characters are converted before insertion and the result is as if the user is entering the characters with the shift key pressed.

But I get an exception when entering data into the `CustomEntry` widget I get the following exception form the `result = self.tk.call(cmd)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rhkea/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/custom_entry_box.py", line 57, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\rhkea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1283, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:/Users/rhkea/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/custom_entry_box.py", line 34, in _proxy
    result = self.tk.call(cmd)
_tkinter.TclError: selection isn't in widget .!frame.!customentry
```

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of stacktraces. They aren't searchable, and the visually impaired can't read them at all.

Comment: Ok - changed to show the exception as text.

Comment: It's best to include the whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with the code, I have found out that after inserting text in the entry, the method `index sel.first` is called. But there is no selection so an error is raised "selection isn't in widget .!frame.!customentry". I don't know how this is handled in a regular `Entry` but you can catch this error:

```
class CustomEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)

    def _proxy(self, *args):
        if args[0] == "insert" and args[1] == "insert":
            args = ('insert', 'insert', args[2].upper())
        cmd = (self._orig,) + args

        try:
            return self.tk.call(cmd)
        except TclError as e:
            if args[0] == 'index' and args[1] == 'sel.first':
                pass
            else:
                raise TclError(str(e))
```

Otherwise, you can use an altogether different method to change the case of the inserted text: use a trace on the textvariable of the entry.

```
class CustomEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._var = StringVar(self)
        self.configure(textvariable=self._var)
        self._var.trace_add('write', self._uppercase)

    def _uppercase(self, *args):
        self._var.set(self._var.get().upper())
```

With `self._var.trace_add('write', self._uppercase)`, the method `_uppercase()` is called each time the content of the `StringVar` changes.